# Set up dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have just installed ubuntu onto the same hdd where my windows is. It's on another partition. When I start my computer, windows starts up. I would like to set up a dualboot choice-screen, but have no idea how to do that.

Please help.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu did you install a boot loader? E.g grub or lilo

Comment: no, I was not offered such option

Comment: OK so can you currently use your Ubuntu partition and if so how?

Comment: no, I can not use it

Comment: So that means there is no boot loader.  Do you still have a live CD? If so you will need to run that and then do some commands to install a boot loader. http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html this is a guide. To installing which may be easier if there is no data to be lost

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader OR: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair